# Which type of patch panel for home network

Tags: networking, home-networking

Lots of information out there but hard to get some help!

I need a patch panel (at least 16 ports) for a cat6a home network (shielded cables) but what type of patch panel!

I don't expect to move the panel, cables or to use any type other than ethernet after installing it but you never know.

So what type of patch panel would be the most appropriate?

- punch-down
- feed through coupler keystone
- punch-down keystone with a keystone frame

I am planning to buy some faceplate and shielded keystone cat6a ready for 10G.

I am aware that the keystone solution will be slightly expensive however for only 16 ports I am not sure it will make a huge difference.

Any recommendation for the type of panel the most suited for my situation?

Comment: https://hardware-recommendations.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was hoping to get some advice regarding a type of panel and not a specific model and who else to know better than people here :-)

Comment: As a ham and a former Telco tech & sysadmin, I'd save your pesos and do punchdown. Worked well enough in umpteen wire centers and central offices.

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice :-)